# How can I connect Project Issues to Project Deliverables in a Post-Mortem document?

Tags: documentation, postmortem, templates

I'm conducting a Post-Mortem Review with Senior Management, regarding a project that had multiple unfulfilled/half-fulfilled deliverables that caused issues for clients. The deliverable for the Post-Mortem is a document that should link issues to unfulfilled/half-fulfilled project deliverables.

How can I ensure the format of the Post-Mortem connects Project Issues to Project Deliverables?

Comment: Hi Andrew, welcome to Project Management Stack Exchange, the Q&A site for project managers. Can you [edit] and tell us more about the problem you hope this will solve? Answers in the Q&A format typically work better when we know more details about *your* specific problem. Please see [ask] for more guidance. Good luck, and welcome to PMSE! :)

Comment: @Andrew - Can you provide more details on what you are trying to accomplish, what are the key items you are looking for, etc? Your question as written is very broad and you are likely to not get what you need.

Comment: I think it is an excellent question.

Comment: If anyone has an answer, I'd say go for it, but just keep your eyes on your post in case Andrew provides some updates, this way you can be sure to update your answer as well, if need be. Good luck!

Comment: Additional Details:  Looking to Conduct a Post Mortem Review with Senior Management, regarding a Project that had multiple unfulfilled/half-fulfilled deliverables, that caused issues for Clients.  Looking for a Word, Excel, Visio, or Powerpoint Template to conduct Post Mortem Analsysis, linking Issues to unfulfilled/half-fulfilled Project Deliverables.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Andrew While answers often contain links to templates, PMSE isn't a search or referral engine. I've refactored your question to address *what* your deliverable needs to contain so that it's not marked as an off-topic "shopping" question. Please feel free to edit further, especially with details about what you've already tried to build and why it isn't working for you.

Comment: Great edits, @CodeGnome! :)

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, I cannot recommend you a fixed template of Word/Excel/PowerPoint or other template, but I hope, that this answer can help you by creating one.

A Postmortem Analysis is composed by a meeting and a documentation. Their base idea is the same, to figure out why was the client lost or why did the project fail. The investigation has to be documented. I propose the following document structure:

- **Short presentation** of the project:

  1. Project's aim, what wanted the client to see
  2. Team members, everyone's role in the project
  3. Planned time, deadlines and milestones
  4. Team member's role, responsibilities, tasks
  5. Resources, data requests [for ex. design elements from the clients] with deadlines
- **Project analysis** - [risk management](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IT_risk_management), if your team member's professional level is at the needed level (this idea doesn't appear in many studies, but I think it's a base thing), if you have the needed device background (I mean, it's pretty hard to develop a mobile application without device, only on simulator).
- Present the **realized part** of the project: where did it stop, until the "dead" what task were completed/began.
- **The breakup**: in what circumstances was the project declared [failed](http://www.mindtools.com/pages/article/newPPM_58.htm); what exactly happened - in details; identify everybody who was in case, directly or in indirect mode. This is the critical part of the analysis. People hate critics (it's a normal thing), but you have to do your best and be real (*avoid to kick the goal* to the other team members), but you have to think that the people working in your team have *[responsibility](http://www.projecttimes.com/george-pitagorsky/failed-projects-who-is-responsible.html)*, and this means to *stand up* and *confess* the decisions even in failed cases.
  This should be the descriptive part of the analysis, where you take out each failed issue, and describe it's details.
- **Conclusion**: what should be modified next time, situations to avoid, paradigms to be fixed at the beginning of the project.

If you will take a presentation/meeting about the failed project, it should go through the steps presented upper, with highlighting the risky points and the failures. In many cases, not only one failure brings to the whole project dead, there should be a range of failures.

**EDIT:**  If you would like to read a little bit more about this, I suggest [this](http://www.slideshare.net/Jaiveer/post-mortem-analysis#btnNext) (especially slide nr. 19), [this](http://ericjacques.org/2010/04/29/postmortem-analysis-process/) and [this](http://www.continuitycentral.com/feature0755.html) link to be useful.

Comment: What went wrong, why it went wrong, and what lessons can be learned...I think that's a good summary of what you said above, and a solid framework to start with.

Answer (score 1):

This is fairly easy. Break it down the same you did to plan the project and follow the paths - scope to deliverables to tasks to responsibilities.

Outline the scope and what specific deliverables were required. Then review what in the scope and deliverables wasn't completed, and what were the issues that prevented it.